# hide edit button if column1!=draft in a list

Tags: javascript, ootb

I have a list and an edit button associated with each list item. The list contains another column called 'status'. I want to display that edit button if and only if status column value is not equals to Draft. Each record contains one of 7 status.

Thanks

Comment: Share you existing code

Comment: can you please suggest any ootb way or doing it with the help of workflow.

Comment: Workflow can not do anything here. How did you add the button? Just share that code, then I will be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

I Created a workflow to do this by removing edit permissions. The button is still there but it does the job.

1. I have a 2010 workflow run and pause until field equals no
2. Then it replaces all the permissions on the item to read and give the group that needs edit rights, edit permissions.
3. For my workflow I gave edit permissions back at the end.

You can see my workflow below.
[image: Workflow]